# CSS: Method for scaling down inherited font size?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I'm trying to add content to the `::after` pseudo-element for each hyperlink with target "_blank".

However, the various `a` elements each have different sizes, and I want the content in the `::after` element to scale with that.

For example, if the `a` element has `font-size: 10px;`, I want the added content to have `font-size: 8px;` - a constant scale of 80% of the parent contents' size.

Without adding classes to each `a` element, is there a way in CSS to take the inherited font-size and scale it?

```css
a[target=_blank]::after {
  content: " bar";
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Foo</a>
<br>
<a href="#" target="_blank">Foo</a>
```

Comment: You already talked about relative sizes using percent, have you tried that? Because that solves your problem.

Comment: @AndersRehn It doesn't seem to be working - at 80% the `after` content is much larger than the element content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.8em = 80% of the current font-size:

```css
a[target="_blank"] {
     font-size: 25px;
}
a[target=_blank]::after {
  content: " bar";
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Foo</a>
<br>
<a href="#" target="_blank">Foo</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, perfect, will accept this as an answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Or simply use `font-size: 80%`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `em` rather than `px`. `em` elements are relative to their container. `font-size: 1em;` means 100 percent font size of it's parent's `font-size`. If your parent element has a `font-size` of `16px` and you give one of it's children a `font-size` of `1em`, the font size will be calculated to `16px` (`1em` = 100% of parents font size) depending on its parent's font size.

Here is a demo:

```css
a {
  font-size: 20px; 
}
a[target="_blank"]::after {
  content: ' bar';
  font-size: 0.8em; /*80% of it's parent*/
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Foo</a>
<br>
<a href="#" target="_blank">Foo</a>
```